# Scraping html data using php

Tags: php, html

How to `parse` the `HTML data` to an `PHP array PHP`

**HTML Data**

```
<div class="test">
    <strong>ID</strong>
    <a href="a.html" title="a html">123456</a><br>
    <label class='label'>Occupation </label>    
    House wife      <br>
    <label>Language?</label>    
    English     <br>
    <label style="width:50%">Basic Language Knowledge of?</label>   
    Hindi       <br>
    <label>Start date</label>
    Nov 2013        <br>
    <label>Other Info</label>
    yes     <br>
    <label>age</label>
    19      <br>
    <label>Gender</label>   
    Female      <br>
    <strong>Address</strong>
    India       <br><br>
    <p>Hi, <br>
Lorem ipsum doner inut</p>
</div>
```

I tried this,

```
<?php
    $html='Let above html to parse';
    preg_match_all('/<label\s(.*)>(.*)<\/label>/U',$html,$m);
    print_r($m);
    // gives all label contents only but I need pair of label text 
    // and value showing after it
?>
```

**Output** like,

> Array('ID'=>123456,'link'=>'a.html','Occupation'=>'House
> wife','Language?'=>'English', 'Basic Language Knowledge
> of?'=>'Hindi','Start date'=>'Nov 2013','Other Info'=>'yes'
> ,'age'=>'19','Gender'=>'Female','Address'=>'India','description'=>'Hi,
> Lorem ipsum doner inut');

Yes, `forgot to mention` I am using [ganon](http://code.google.com/p/ganon/) for `scraping`

Comment: so what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php) to parse HTML.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
```

And use [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to get all your labels:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$allLabels = $xpath->query('//label');

foreach($allLabels as $label) {
    var_dump($label, $label->nodeValue);

    /* or */
    $labelElmnts = $xpath->query('/*', $label);

    $innerHTML = '';

    foreach($labelElmnts as $elmnt)
        $innerHTML .= $domDoc->saveHTML($elmnt);

    var_dump($innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: It will only give the list of `label data and I need the text after label data like, `occupation=>'house wife'`

Comment: Read the doc: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php. `->nodeValue` is what you're looking for. Have a look at my edited code in t he answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even easier solution.

Use [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/):

```
foreach(qp($html, 'label') as $label){
  echo $label->text();
}
```

Just like jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I used `ganon` so I don't want to use `Dom Document` I tried it something and `worked` like,

```
// for description
echo $desc=$html('div.right_div p',0)->getInnerText();

$s=$html('div.right_div',0)->getInnerText();

// for occupation
$r='/<label>\s*Occupation\s*<\/label>\s*(.*)\s*<br\s*[\/]>/i';
preg_match_all($r,$s,$ma);
echo $occupation=$ma[1];

// for address
$r='/<strong>\s*Address\s*<\/strong>\s*(.*)\s*<br\s*[\/]>/i';
preg_match_all($r,$s,$ma);
echo $address=$ma[1];

// for id
echo $id=$html('div.right_div a',0)->getInnerText();
```

And so on **...**